# Get value from nested form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following dynamically created form inputs:

```
<input class='dr-currency-rate form-control' type='text' name='dr_entry[][dr_rate]' id='dr_entry[][dr_rate]'>
```

What I'm trying to do is get the value from each input field with javascript fro rate calculation.

Following is not working:

```
.find("input[name^='dr_entry[][dr_rate]']").val();
```

Comment: if the quering context is referring to an ancestor element of the said input then it should work - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pk8woby7/1/ (assuming the input is present in the dom when the script is executed)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can find it in document as below, since its a dynamic element:

```
$(document).find("input[name^='dr_entry[][dr_rate]']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are generated with the same value as the name attribute, it's much faster to look up an element by id than to perform a find on an attribute value. 
`$('#dr_entry[][dr_rate]').val();`

Comment: same escaping issue as above ...your selector won't work as is